# Difference between Intel MEI and Intel ME

Tags: drivers

I have a 8th series Intel CPU and I want to Install the drivers for it but there are some programs similar to each other. one of them is Intel ME 1.5 MB and 5 MB and MEI. I searched for them and it appears that (5MB) version of ME has more features than 1.5 MB so its setup file is smaller (comparing to 90MB size of ME 5MB). so I installed the 5MB version and now I have Intel Security Assist and Intel Management Engine Components and Intel Anti Theft Technology. do I need to install MEI (Management Engine Interface) too? what's the advantage of installing them both? Thanks.

Comment: [MEI is software and drivers, ME is firmware](http://www.win-raid.com/t596f39-Intel-Management-Engine-Drivers-Firmware-amp-System-Tools.html)

Comment: The information about each software was useful but there are many websites like necacom.net and I use it to find latest drivers and they don't put packages like that. Where should i use as a reference to download these updates?

Comment: [I get mine from Intel.](http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/detect)

Comment: Unfortunately it fails to identify the drivers on my PC but on laptop it identifies almost all of them.

Comment: Strange issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, you don't NEED to install the MEI, but if you do, it has the ability to give you extended stats about Intel components. So as such, it is advisable.

Comment: They appeared in Windows updates. so you're suggesting that I only need the ME 5MB, and not MEI, right?

Comment: @Stephan pretty much, because WU should roll it out to you if you install optional updates